# Problems with connecting to internet, except for Internet Explorer, OneDrive and Office

Tags: windows, networking, internet, internet-explorer

Since a few days or so, I have a problem with internet connection on my Windows 8.1 Lenovo laptop. Connecting to Wi-Fi works fine and I can also browse the internet using Internet Explorer - also connecting to OneDrive or checking E-Mails via MS Office works perfectly well.

Now my Problem is, that I can only connect to the Internet using those programs. E.g.: lately I tried to download InDesign CC but Adobe Creative Cloud was not able to connect to its Servers. Same thing with Firefox, Thunderbird and so on.

<s>I also checked the Proxy settings - they should be okay.</s> I am not using any proxy.

Has anybody an idea what to do?

Comment: Is Firefox using the proxy? It has its own settings, whereas Microsoft programs always use the system settings, I think.

Comment: No, it's not. The strange thing is, that the problem occurs with every single programm except those from Microsoft. Also advertisements e.g. in WinRAR are not displayed due to failing to connect to the Internet.

Comment: If Firefox (and the other software, I assume) is not using the proxy, then why are you using proxy settings to start with? (My guess is that the Microsoft software will stop working too, when you disable the proxy. Or that Firefox will work if you make it use the system proxy settings.)

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe that was a bit unclear. I am not using any proxy at all.

Comment: Did you check if internet explorer is using proxy? You can also download wireshark to capture packets.

Comment: Internet Explorer isn't using Proxy, too. I have also deactivated Windows Firewall and Norton - nothing has changed.